# Change just a part of the dom when modifying url in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

Creating an web application to display some news, I want it to be a single page app, where articles are display as list, showing only the title, and (when clicking on the title), opening to display the content.

I've done that, but now I want to modify the url so it adapt to the opened article without having to reload the entire page. I've followed the child routing component and some answer here, but nothing else happens that a

> Cannot find primary outlet to load ''

displayed in the console. Here is the code :

app/app.routes.ts :

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig }  from '@angular/router';
import { articlesRoutes } from './articles/articles.routes';
import { ArticlesComponent } from "./articles/articles.component";

const routes: RouterConfig = [
    ...articlesRoutes,
];

export const appRouterProviders = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

app/articles/articles.routes.ts :

```
import {ArticlesComponent} from "./articles.component";
import {RouterConfig} from "@angular/router";
import {ArticleDetailComponent} from "./detail/article-detail.component";

export const articlesRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ArticlesComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'detail/:id',  component: ArticleDetailComponent
            },
        ]
    }
];
```

app/articles/articles.component.html

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ArticleService } from "./shared/article.service";
import { Article } from "./shared/article.model";
import { ArticleDetailComponent } from "./detail/article-detail.component";
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES }  from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'fcso-articles',
    templateUrl: 'app/articles/articles.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ArticleService],
})
export class ArticlesComponent implements OnInit {
    articles: Article[] = [];
    articleOpened: Article = null;
    error: any;

    constructor(
        private articleService: ArticleService,
        private router: Router) {}

    getArticles() {
        this.articleService
            .getArticles()
            .then(articles => this.articles = articles)
            .catch(error => this.error = error);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getArticles();
    }

    //function changing the hidden article and redirecting to URL
    gotoDetail(article: Article) {
        this.articleOpened = article;
        this.router.navigate(['', '/detail', this.articleOpened.id]);
    }
}
```

index.html

```
    <body>
      <!-- the main content (from app.component.ts) is not loaded from router -->
      <fcso-main>
        Loading...
      </fcso-main>
    </body>
```

app/app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 fcso-no-padding">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h1 class="text-center">Title</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- this router outlet should show articlesComponent -->
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

app/articles/articles.component.html

```
<div class="panel panel-default" *ngFor="let article of articles">
    <div class="panel-heading fcso-panel-heading" *ngIf="article !== articleOpened" >
        <h3 class="text-center fcso-open-panel" (click)="gotoDetail(article)">{{article.title}}</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- router-outler is hidden to boost angular perfs and avoid troubles -->
    <router-outlet *ngIf="article === articleOpened"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I also try to move the content of articles.routes.ts directly to app.routes.ts, without any changing. I tried to put only the parent in app.routes.ts. It load the list of articles, but it doesn't load the child content, with this error code :

> Cannot find primary outlet to load 'ArticleDetailComponent'

I tried to use routerConfig in the .component.ts, didn't influence too.

What do I have to do to get the child (ArticleDetailComponent) displayed at the place off the clicked title with a url modification ?

Comment: Could you remove `*ngIf` in `<router-outlet>`? It may interfere with the way Angular router works.

Comment: It didn't change anything. I tried when I had the error on the Child, and still didn't change anything. I think it's because of the articles.component.ts => gotoDetail(), which show the router-outlet before calling the router.

Answer (score 0):

- You create `<router-outlet>` inside an `*ngFor`. There can only be one `<router-outlet>` without a name and the others need to have distinct names. Creating them with `*ngFor` creates an arbitrary number of nameless `<router-outlet>` which is invalid.
- The spread operator is missing

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  ... articlesRoutes,
];
```

- For the child routes a default route is missing

```
export const articlesRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: ArticlesComponent, children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'detail/01', pathMatch: 'full'}, /* required */
    { path: 'detail/:id',  component: ArticleDetailComponent },
  ]}
];
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/R0KTxRCIt1fT40loLY2g?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have to say that I already read in stack overflow the suggestion of a name (for the <router-outler>)  but I remember it's not in this version of the angular-routing. Plus, it's not on the official doc, so, should I use the selector instead ?
About your suggestion for the required element (last point). Wouldn't it prevent to use what's in my "ArticlesComponent" by calling "ArticleDetailComponent" ?

Comment: Its called aux routes and it has some limited support but several bugs that should be fixed with the next update. The "required" so it doesn't result in an error when the page is loaded without any path. You can also use `component: DummyComponent` instead of `redirectTo: '....'` to show nothing in this case.